# How to cluster in Nodejs - just local calculations

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodejs in order to do some computations (No express app!).

My file "calculations.js" is going through a huge array of data and does a lot of calculations. In the end, I receive a simple result.

As the computations are heavy and only one of my 16 cores are used, it still takes a lot of time on my rig.

How can I utilize my 16 cores? All examples with regard to the Cluster Module of nodejs always assume some kind of http connection.

I tried the following without luck:

```
//cluster.js
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = 16;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
}
} else {
require('./calculations');
}
```

EDIT:

```
//calculations.js
const array = [{name: "target"},{name:"walmart"},{}, etc. ] // 150 objects

array.map((supermarket) => {
calculationFunction(supermarket.name);
}
```

EDIT: For me it would help a lot, if the array.map function would be somehow "clustered" - meaning that the 150 calls of the function "calculationFunction" would be distributed over my 16 cores. That should be easily possible, no!?

It seems that my file "calculations" is now just started 16x, but in the same way. So the time for the process actually got much longer!?

Help is very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: The cluster module will not help you here.  It is for web servers only.  To use more CPUs for plain calculations, you will have to break your process down into sub-tasks and create a number of child processes that you give sub-tasks to.  We can't help with the details on how to break it into sub-tasks without knowing a lot more about the type of calculations your'e doing and seeing the existing code for that.

Comment: @jfriend00 that not exactly true. `cluster` does not only make it easier to _shares_ the sockets, but it also implements a system to send messages between the forked processes. So it can be used make it easier to split and sync the work between those processes, without the need to implement an ipc protocol yourself.

Comment: @t.niese - OK fine.  The point is that the OP needs to break their work into chunks and distribute them manually to child processes.  The cluster module will not do that for them.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your coment. I updated the example a bit. Could you somehow hint in the right direction with the edited example? Thanks a lot

Comment: Create 16 child processes.  Send each one a `supermarket.name` and have it do calculation on that and send you back a result.  When it sends back a result, you send it another name.  You put the `calculationFunction()` inside the child processes and it runs there.  Probably easiest to manage it with a work-queue and a set of worker child processes.

Comment: @jfriend00 this sounds like exactly what I was looking for. As I am quite new to porgramming, seeing a few lines of simplified code of how that would look like would help me tremendously.

Comment: Some ideas [bee-queue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue), [Kue](https://blog.jscrambler.com/queue-jobs-kue/), [Taking advantage of multi-processor environments in nodejs](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/28/taking-advantage-of-multi-processor-environments-in-node-js/) and plenty more articles in [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+implement+work+queue+multiple+processes+nodejs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, this is one of the limitations of node.js and most other languages too. because node is single-threaded it only uses one of your machines core and simulate multi-threading using asynchronous/non-blocking design.

Cluster wont help you because it creates multiple instance of your script on each core but they all are doing the same task each without communication so its useless for you.

what you could do is divide your code into multiple chunks of standalone code and create a child-process to run on different cores so that the code uses your machines code more effectively.

Or rewrite it in [golang](https://golang.org) :) which would make it easy for you to utilize all your machine's cores.

Comment: If you picked a language with threads (like C++), you'd still have to break the work up into chunks and run each chunk in a thread and develop thread-safe communication.  With node.js, you get multiple CPUs involved by creating child processes and communicating among the processes.

Comment: creating a child process sounds interesting. How could that look like with my array.map function?